# Использование слова «идеал» вместо соответствующего прилагательного

Tags: грамматика

Очень хотелось бы узнать, правильно ли с грамматической, стилистической и т. д. точек зрения следующее предложение:

**«Я не идеал»**?

Почему-то оно мне режет уши. Я бы использовала вместо него предложение

**«Я не идеальна»** или **«Я далеко не идеал»**,

но увы: ритм не позволяет.

Comment: Где я точно не вижу ни малейшей стилистической (и уж тем более грамматической) разницы — так это между _я не идеал_, которое вам режет слух, и _я далеко не идеал_, которое вы бы использовали.

 
Что до вопроса по существу, то грамматической ошибки я тут не вижу. А чтоб оценивать, уместно ли выражение стилистически, надо знать, какого стиля вы хотите придерживаться. –

Comment: если напрячься, то можно углядеть семантическую разницу

Comment: @MolbOrg, вы, я так понимаю, ожидаете вопроса: «И какую же?».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С грамматической точки зрения всё нормально, с фактическим словоупотреблением - тоже.

Другое дело, что такое словоупотребление лежит в области очень-очень тонких особенностей, делающих изучение иностранных языков таким сложным делом.

Сравните с "Я далеко не гений" и "Я не гениален". Так сказать можно, это абсолютная норма.
А например форма "Я [далеко] не дурак" единственно употребимая, "я не дурацкий" никто не скажет, скажет "я не глуп[ый/ая]".

Все эти словосочетания и оттенки их употребления остаётся только выучить.

А ещё, судя по вашему вопросу, вам кажется что слово "далеко" на что-то в данном контексте влияет. Но это предположение неверно точно, в данном случае ни на что не влияет.

Comment: Здесь-то как раз ничего странного нет — у "дурака" нет *«соответствующего»* прилагательного, как и у большинства существительных. То, что "гений", "идеал", "красавец" описывают воплощение некоторого качества, и тесно связаны по смыслу с прилагательным, больше совпадение, чем правило. Учить тут не надо ровным счётом ничего. Нельзя быть "учительским", "мамашным", "менеджериальным", "дальнобойным" и т.п. Просто мимо.

Comment: @Shady_arc вы тут в одну кучу кидаете прилагательные которых попросту нет с прилагательными, которые всё таки есть и образуют пару с существительным.

Comment: А есть ли "пары"? Первый раз слышу о таком явлении в русском.

Comment: @Shady_arc OK, вы выразили своё несогласие, вас услышат все, кто прочтут этот коммент.

Answer (score 0):

Идеал - существительное, обозначающее недостижимый образец для подражания (нечно идеальное). Получается предложение со сказуемым-существительным, которое вполне подходит по значению.